# Work-around for 255 character WHERE clause limit in Access 2010 Web database macro?

Tags: sharepoint-2010, ms-access-2010, where-clause

I'm creating a web application using the 2010 Access Services SharePoint 2010 publication tools.

I am currently creating a reporting page where the user can toggle multiple drop-down menus to filter the results of a report.  The problem is, the `WHERE` clause filter in the macro editor has a 255 character limit, which allows me to only apply 3 `WHERE` criteria, (and I need to employ ~8 criteria).  Does anyone have a work-around for this problem where I can perhaps nest multiple dynamic `WHERE` clauses or something?  I've already employed aliases to make the condition statement about as short as possible.  It currently reads as:

```
BrowseTo
  Object Type: Report
  Object Name: rptSA_Report
  Path to Subform Control: frmMainMenu.NavigationSubForm>frmQueryFilters.subrMaster
  Where Condition: ([TempVars]![SF] Is Null Or [SF]=[TempVars]![SF]) And ([TempVars]![P] Is Null Or [P1]=[TempVars]![P] Or [P2]=[TempVars]![P]) And ([TempVars]![PA] Is Null Or [PA1]=[TempVars]![PA] Or [PA2]=[TempVars]![PA])
  Page:
  Data Mode: Read Only
```

I'm aware that there are a ton of limitations with the Access/SharePoint Web Services, but I'm hoping someone has a functional work-around for this issue in particular.

I've already tried building a string temporary variable and using that in the `WHERE` clause, but the report wouldn't recognize the parameters when they're buried in a string variable.

Comment: Not sure if Sharepoint will let you or not, but if you can run the command to convert macros to VBA, you can use string variable type to exceed this limitation - is this on a form or just from drop down menu?

Comment: @dbmitch Unfortunately, everything I've read thus far tells me that Access Web databases have to keep all of the 'code' in the standardized macro-format so that it can translate itself to javascript on the sync to the web server.  The code is attached to a form with a sub-report control, a bunch of drop-down combo boxes (for the user to filter with) and a "query!" command button (this is where the filtering BrowseTo macro lies).